# Can NUnit expect a timeout?

Tags: c#, timeout, nunit, nunit-2.5

I would like to test a method that I am expecting to block in a specific situation.

I tried a combination of the `TimeoutAttribute` and `ExpectedExceptionAttribute`:

```
[Test]
[Timeout(50), ExpectedException(typeof(ThreadAbortException))]
public void BlockingCallShouldBlock()
{
    this.SomeBlockingCall();
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as the `ThreadAbortException` I was reading about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448523/1811525) seems to get caught by NUnit itself.

Is there a way to expect timeouts (with NUnit)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a problem like this, I would probably use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Task.Wait(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Task.Wait(TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
[Test]
public void BlockingCallShouldBlock()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => SomeBlockingCall());
    var completedInTime = task.Wait(50); // Also an overload available for TimeSpan
    Expect(completedInTime, Is.False);
}
```

Be warned however, this will invoke `SomeBlockingCall` on a background thread, but for the majority of unit tests, this is a non-issue.